# Plugin or ways to limit number of users logging in the website,

Tags: plugins, php, login, user-access, session

Would like to check if there is any way (or plugin) available that can:
a.limit the number of concurrent users session by of user currently logged in to the website
b.limit the number of users logging in to the website.

(E.g. If I set the max session to be 200. The 201st users who try to access will redirect to a page informing website is experiencing heavy traffic and request him/her to come back at a later time.)

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Loggedin – Limit Active Logins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/loggedin/).